# How can I grep or cat files which begin with a specific number until another specific number?

Tags: linux, grep, cat

I would like to grep or cat only files that begin with a specific number and are in a range until a specific number, e.g.:

```
abc_server.2022-04-09-34.log
```

until

```
abc_server.2022-04-09-50.log
```

How can I do this?

I tried using cat:
`cat abc_server.2022-04-09-3*`
but obviously it does not give me the expected results.

Comment: Try `abc_server.2022-04-09-{34..50}.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) for numeric ranges. Here's an example:

```bash
$ echo file_{09..12}.txt
file_09.txt file_10.txt file_11.txt file_12.txt
```

Note that this is not wildcard matching. The expansion happens irrespective of whether files with those names exist.

So, if you use `cat file_{09..12}.txt`, the four filenames shown above will be passed as arguments to the `cat` command.